# youtube embed player shows html5 3D video in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, youtube, embed

The video shows a normal chrome. In the transition to viewing on the YouTube channel - also, the only problem firefox 40.0.2.
Screenshot https://yadi.sk/i/NUlpn8BTidhFv
The problem in this http://beoff.ru/?p=74680 and some other pages.

Embedded by such a query:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $ tubes?>? rel = 0 & amp; autoplay = 1
```

In what may be a problem in firefox?

Comment: I found the problem. In Russian she described her decision. http://wppost.ru/post-group/html5-video-and-firefox-ustranyaem-problemu/ Thread can be closed as a solution. Do not delete - help others

Comment: A link only comment answer that is in Russian should not be the reason to not close / delete an SO question.  If you really want to help others, please translate into English and post it as an answer.

Comment: Changed domain, Topical solution https://codeseller.ru/post-group/html5-video-and-firefox-ustranyaem-problemu/